# WPF DataGrid only allow selection when condition

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm working on a C# project where i have a DataGrid which containts objects:
[DataGrid picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPlBX.png)

My main goal here is that the User can select only **one "BUY"** type of object.
(Multiselect is true of course)
If he tries to select another , nothing will change, the selections stay the same.
However he can select as many **"SELL"** type of object as he wants to.

But my code doesn't seem to work, how could i solve this problem ?

CODE:

```
<DataGrid Name="TransactionTableXAML" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=tableAttributes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="TransactionTableXAML_SelectionChanged"/>

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool boughtSelected = false;
    public int currentBoughtIndex;
    private void TransactionTableXAML_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         boughtSelected = false;
         if(TransactionTableXAML.SelectedItem!=null)
         {
             var itemsSource = TransactionTableXAML.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
             if (itemsSource != null)
             {
                  foreach (var item in itemsSource)
                  {
                      var dataGridRow = TransactionTableXAML.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                      var stock = (MyObject)item;
                      if (boughtSelected == false)
                      {
                         if (stock.getTransactionType() == "BUY")
                         {
                             currentBoughtIndex = dataGridRow.GetIndex();
                         }

                      }
                      else if(boughtSelected==true && stock.getTransactionType()=="BUY" && currentBoughtIndex!=dataGridRow.GetIndex())
                      {
                          dataGridRow.IsSelected = false;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Personally, I would bind a collection of stock. Bind isselected to a property in stock, or whatever each item is. I'd pass a reference in to a parent viewmodel so each can get at the collection it's in. When isselected changes in stock which is BUY I'd use a line of linq to set other stocks isselected to false.

Comment: Basically my code doesn't work, and i would like to solve this problem.

Comment: How do you feel about the approach I described above? Getting objects out a datagrid is hard work, working with the underlying data is way easier.

Comment: A hint - SelectionChangedEventArgs has Handled property